# Reporting/logging from with in a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an async call that throws an exception if the given record fails processing. That exception is caught as aggregated exception. There is now, a requirement that I have to log a warning message from my async method. I cannot log to TextBox/Grid as it is not allowed to access controls over different threads and I cannot throw an exception as I actually want to log and continue that task. Here is the parent code that launches a task:

```
private List<OrganizationUser> GenerateDataList(string importFilePath, int lastUserId = -1)
{
  var resultList = new List<OrganizationUser>();

  // Note: ReadLine is faster than ReadAllLines
  var lineCount = File.ReadLines(importFilePath).Count();
  LogMessage(new LogEntry(String.Format(" - File has {0} lines.", lineCount)));
  var consistancyCounter = 0;

  ResetProgress();

  using (var fs = File.Open(importFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
  {
    using (var bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    {
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(bs))
      {
        string readLine;
        while ((readLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(readLine) || readLine == "---EOF---")
          {
            break;
          }

          try
          {
            var processLineTask = Task.Run(() => GenerateDataListInternal(nextId++, localReadLine, localConsistancyCounter));
            processLineTask.Wait();

            var result = processLineTask.Result;

            if (result != null)
            {
              resultList.Add(result);
            }
          }
          catch (AggregateException exp)
          {
            if (exp.InnerExceptions.Count == 1 && exp.InnerExceptions.Any(x => x is DataFileBadColumnNumbers || x is DataFileGenerateListException))
            {
              LogMessage(new LogEntry(exp.InnerExceptions[0].Message, LogEntryType.Warning));
            }
            else if (exp.InnerExceptions.Count == 1 && exp.InnerExceptions.Any(x => x is IndexOutOfRangeException))
            {
              LogMessage(new LogEntry(String.Format(" - Data cannot be parsed at line #{0}. Data is: {1}", localConsistancyCounter + 1, localReadLine), LogEntryType.Warning));
            }
            else
            {
              throw;
            }
          }
        }

        if (ProgressBarImport.Value <= ProgressBarImport.Maximum)
        {
          ProgressBarImport.PerformStep();
        }   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, `GenerateDataListInternal` is the method that throws exceptions and now needs to log.

How can I log from within the `GenerateDataListInternal` method? I have tried the delegate approach and that simply hangs the application. I have a method that logs to Console, Grid and text file (in that order). Any call to that method from asynced methods fail due to Cross thread operation.

Comment: Have you tried Log4net?

Comment: Logging is already done through NLog and I'm to use the provided API through the NLogFactory.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, is a *requirement* to put a message into TextBox/Grid, in addition to logging with NLog?

Comment: If the tool is run as attended, yes, I need to post to a grid/Textbox

Answer (score 4):

This is already provided through the [System.IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and the [Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, where `T` can be any class, allowing you to report much more than a simple progress percentage.

`IProgress<T>.Report` allows you to report progress (or anything else) from inside an asynchronous operation without worrying who will actually handle the report.

`Progress<T>` will call an action and/or raise an event on the thread where it was created (eg. the UI thread) whenever your task calls `.Report`

This example from the [.NET Framework Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) displays how easy it is to use `IProgress<T>`:

```
async Task<int> UploadPicturesAsync(List<Image> imageList, IProgress<int> progress)
{
        int totalCount = imageList.Count;
        int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
        {
            int tempCount = 0;
            foreach (var image in imageList)
            {
                //await the processing and uploading logic here
                int processed = await UploadAndProcessAsync(image);
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Report((tempCount * 100 / totalCount));
                }
                tempCount++;
            }

            return tempCount;
        });
        return processCount;
}
```

The async process starts with this code:

```
private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//construct Progress<T>, passing ReportProgress as the Action<T> 
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
//call async method
    int uploads=await UploadPicturesAsync(GenerateTestImages(), progressIndicator);
}
```

Note that `progressIndicator` is created in the UI thread, so the `ReportProgress` method will be called on the UI thread.

**UPDATE**

From the comments it sounds like you are trying to create your own logging solution and have issues with accessing the log file from multiple threads.

The best solution here would be to use a logging library like `log4net`, `NLog` or even .NET's Diagnostic classes. All of them work without issues with multiple threads.

`IProgress<T>` can still help here, as the delegate that handles a Report event can simply write the message to a log file you already created on the UI thread.

You could write something like this:

```
var progress = new Progress<LogEntry>(entry =>
{
   _logFile.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",entry.EntryType,entry.Message);
});
```

and report from inside a Task  with:

```
var entry=new LogEntry(...);
progress.Report(entry);
```

Comment: I'm making changes as per you code. I now remember `IProgress<>` as I may have used or seen this before in my hobby projects. I'll come back with results soon.

Comment: Ok, you code helps out in reporting progress. I'm reporting a log under a certain case while inside the `UploadAndProcessAsync()` (from you example, for example) method. While my code is process a text line, there is a validation condition and I need to log or report that. For me, a `IProgress<string>`, will not help here.

Comment: Why not? In the original question you said your problem is how to log something to a control. You can do that easily with `IProgress`, evaluating the condition either before calling `Report` or as part of the reporting action. Unless you are creating your own logging and don't want to write to the log from multiple tasks? Just use a logging library. `IProgress can still help` as you can put all logging code in the `Report` delegate that runs on the UI thread, accessing the log file created there

Comment: Like I said, in your example, the Button calls --> UploadPicturesAsync() --> UploadAndProcessAsync(). So, by example, the last worker method is UploadAndProcessAsync(). In my case, this method is GenerateDataListInternal(). That method need to access a UK control. And in your case, UploadPicturesAsync() is accessing the UI... not UploadAndProcessAsync(). I hope I made my self a bit clearer.

Comment: Not really. Neither the blog's example nor the logging example refer to any controls. The whole point is, instead of reporting from inside a Task, marshal a message object to the UI thread through `Report`. Once there, you can do whatever you like.